How do you add a user created RubyGem to a Git local server(local protocol)
I know how to create a git server(local protocol)
git init --bare ~/GitProject/git_projects.git

and I know how to create a RubyGem and check the git status,add, commit
bundle gem arr_util
git status
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial Commit'

Now I want to add my RubyGem to the local git server and this seems to work..
git remote add arr_util ~/GitProject/git_projects.git

git remote -v
arr_util    /home/******/GitProject/git_projects.git (fetch)
arr_util    /home/******/GitProject/git_projects.git (push)

git push --set-upstream arr_util master

do some stuff to RubyGem...
git status
git add .
git commit -m 'RSpec file updated'

git push

And everything seems to work. I can even delete my arr_util folder and call clone on the git local server to restore it.
git clone ~/GitProject/git_projects.git arr_util

So is this the correct way to add a repo to my git local server?
